# Prevent access to method if method parameters don't meet criteria by using attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, attributes

I have multiple simple methods in which I need to restrict access if method parameters don't match the requirement. All methods accept an ID of a currently logged in user as well as a class with a user ID of a record owner.

Within an attribute I need to compare `userId == object.UserId` and allow the method to trigger only if that condition is met.

I began implementing this without using attributes as:

```
public SomeObject SaveMyRecord(string userId, SomeObject object)
{
 if(userId!=object.UserId
 { 
  return null;
 }

 //do stuff with object

}
```

But I really feel that having that repeating `IF` statement in all my "object" methods isn't the best way to go. Is it possible to build a custom method attribute that would restrict these methods being accessesed if `userId!=object.userId` ?

p.s. this is an asp.net mvc app

Comment: are you using a web application? can you use a middleware?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper it's an asp.net mvc app. No, I can't use middleware. Thank you.

Comment: id data annotations good candidates for it?,

Comment: It depends what you mean by restricting access. If you mean you want them to be redirected to the login page then I can post an example of how to do that with an attribute. Unfortunately you cannot prevent users from requesting the method (if it is a controller action linked to a route) however you can hide it from them and you can redirect them to a different url or request them to reauthenticate

Comment: So what you're really looking for is some kind of "automatic" parameter validation?

Comment: @JimMischel Pretty much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these methods are controller actions, you can make use of the `OnActionExecuting` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx

This is called before the action method is invoked so you can perform your check there. You can access the HttpContext so the parameters you pass in will be available.

Comment: Used this approach to create a custom attribute